# Is it true that IE7 doesnt support indexOf javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.indexOf function on an array not working in IE7/8 using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544983/indexof-function-on-an-array-not-working-in-ie7-8-using-javascript)

Im developing for IE7 and have some troubles with the javascript function indexOf.

After browsing some sites I read that IE7 doesnt support indexOf. Is this correct, and if so, whats the easiest way to check if a string contains a given string?

```
var test = window.location.toString();
test = test.toLowerCase();
var idString = "28A3CASDGAGHTSDASF34134";
idString = idString.toLowerCase();
if(test.indexOf(idString) > 0){
  alert('worked');
}
```

Edit:
Most likely some coding error by myself

Comment: Open IE7, enter "javascript:mystring.indexOf("some string")" in the URL bar, hit enter and show what happens..

Comment: Possibly he doesn't have access to IE7.

Comment: well.. I am trying it out, and it seems as it aint supported. Still need an easy way to do indexOf..

Comment: What are "some sites"? Pretty sure they're wrong. And what is your actual problem? i.e. What happens when you try?

Comment: I am trying to do an alert('message to show it occured'). Works fine in Firefox, but no alert in IE7

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, `Array.indexOf` isn't supported, however `String.indexOf`, as per your example above, is.

The best way to work things like this out are to just try them in the browser you're querying. This is much more reliable than asking someone else, people have different browser configurations etc.

Update: See [this MSDN documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53xtt423%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) about indexOf, it's been supported since IE6.

Comment: Hmm. I am trying it with a string..

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a case-sensitive method, does your case match? You could lowercase both strings before doing the `indexOf`, if this is an issue.

Comment: Tried to test that, not the problem :-/

Comment: Well are you getting any errors? It should work fine, updated my answer with a page from MSDN. Is it perhaps that you're using `If` instead of `if`?

Comment: Did you try a debug with `alert(test.indexOf(idString));`, the fact you're not getting an error (I hope) means the function exists.

Comment: indexOf works. It was an error by myself :$