# .indexOf function on an array not working in IE7/8 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Can anyone tell me if IE 7 and IE 8 support the JavaScript .indexOf() method as I am receiving the error:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'
```

from the IE9 debug console (used under both IE7 and IE8 Browser mode).

For the below comment, the code using .indexOf() is as follows:

```
if(shirt_colour == 'black') {
    p_arr=['orange','red','green','yellow','bblue','rblue','pink','white','silver','gold'];
    if( p_arr.indexOf(print_colour) != -1 ) rtn = true;
}
```

Comment: I've used indexOf() since IE3/Netscape 4.7, never with that problem. Are you sure you're using it on a string object? show us the code that returns the error.

Comment: @Guidhouse Any thoughts then based on the above? I would have certainly thought quite a rudimentary function like that would be in IE7.

Comment: The answer to this question does express any thought I have on the subject very well. So i just give that a vote up instead :-)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

On IE<9 `indexOf()` it is not "well" implemented. Try to add this function on your code :

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
{
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/)
  {
    var len = this.length;

    var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
    from = (from < 0)
         ? Math.ceil(from)
         : Math.floor(from);
    if (from < 0)
      from += len;

    for (; from < len; from++)
    {
      if (from in this &&
          this[from] === elt)
        return from;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

It will "replace" the original function, if not found in the ECMA-262 standard.

Answer (score 2):

Following code can be helpful.

```
function findIndexOf(findfrom, findthis) {
    for (i = 0; i < findfrom.length; i++) {
        if (findfrom[i] == findthis) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need `indexOf` in IE<=8, you should consider using the following [polyfill](https://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill), which is [recommended at the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) :

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.14
// Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.14
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(searchElement, fromIndex) {

    var k;

    // 1. Let o be the result of calling ToObject passing
    //    the this value as the argument.
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
    }

    var o = Object(this);

    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get
    //    internal method of o with the argument "length".
    // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
    var len = o.length >>> 0;

    // 4. If len is 0, return -1.
    if (len === 0) {
      return -1;
    }

    // 5. If argument fromIndex was passed let n be
    //    ToInteger(fromIndex); else let n be 0.
    var n = +fromIndex || 0;

    if (Math.abs(n) === Infinity) {
      n = 0;
    }

    // 6. If n >= len, return -1.
    if (n >= len) {
      return -1;
    }

    // 7. If n >= 0, then Let k be n.
    // 8. Else, n<0, Let k be len - abs(n).
    //    If k is less than 0, then let k be 0.
    k = Math.max(n >= 0 ? n : len - Math.abs(n), 0);

    // 9. Repeat, while k < len
    while (k < len) {
      // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
      //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
      // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the
      //    HasProperty internal method of o with argument Pk.
      //   This step can be combined with c
      // c. If kPresent is true, then
      //    i.  Let elementK be the result of calling the Get
      //        internal method of o with the argument ToString(k).
      //   ii.  Let same be the result of applying the
      //        Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm to
      //        searchElement and elementK.
      //  iii.  If same is true, return k.
      if (k in o && o[k] === searchElement) {
        return k;
      }
      k++;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```