# Javascript IndexOf (String) in IE

Tags: javascript, string, internet-explorer, indexof

As far as I know, IE supports "indexOf" on strings. However, my javascript code doesn't do the same when I execute it on IE or Chrome.

This is my code

```
function initHidden() {
    //Some code here

   var campos = "a;A;A;A;A;A;A;A" // <- Not the real data. In real situation this is set calling a function which return a string with this format
   var camposcheck = "a" // <- Same as other
   if (campos != null && campos != "") {
       var items = campos.split(";");
       for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
           if (camposcheck.indexOf(item[i]) > -1 || camposcheck.indexOf(item[i] + ";")  > -1) alert("YES");
           else alert("NO");
       }
    }
}
```

In Chrome, I get: YES

In IE, I get: NO

Comment: possible duplicate of [.indexOf function on an array not working in IE7/8 using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544983/indexof-function-on-an-array-not-working-in-ie7-8-using-javascript)

Comment: Just a quick hint: never make an if statement inside a for-loop. Imagine your `items.length` is about 1000 and each time it must check your if statement - that would slow down your website immense.

Comment: Your IE version? Also `item` isn't define, It should be `items[i]`

Comment: @RossTurner the link is for arrays not for strings.

Comment: @RahilWazir My Ie version is 11.0.9600.17207. And item was a "copy-paste" error xd

Comment: @Rumpel Both in IE and Chrome i'm recieving `Yes` then series of `No, No....`

Comment: @RahilWazir Thanks for you time. I could solve problem using "search" instead of "indexof"