# Javascript - Removing an entry from array directly

Tags: javascript

I have an array of `users`. Each of these `user` have some context, but also some functions.

Normally, to delete one of these `users`, one could use `users.splice(index, 1)` with `index` being the index of interest.

However, I want to add a function `remove()` to each of these users, and then want to remove them by simply invoking `user.remove()` and this should remove the `user` from `users`.

Could this be done?

Comment: Not sure this is a good idea. Objects are references, when you remove it from somewhere, you remove a reference to that object. I would name the method `user.removeFrom(users)`. That makes it more reusable, and more explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a remove-function to the prototype of the users which has access to the users-array (via closure or other references).

```
var users = [];
User.prototype.remove = function() {
    var index = users.indexOf(this);
    users.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be a memory leak?

Comment: watch out for usage of `indexOf` < ie 9 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544983/indexof-function-on-an-array-not-working-in-ie7-8-using-javascript

Comment: @SteveHollasch: If aUser.remove() is called, aUser is removed from the users-array. When there is no other reference to aUser, the GC will collect it because there is no way to access the instance.
As long as the User.prototype exists, the users-array itself is probably never collected by the GC, because the User.prototype.remove-function could always access the array. But I don't think this is a memory leak since the array will be empty if all users were removed. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Ottis: Yes, I think you're right. Removing a user from the array will delete one reference in the loop, which makes the user available for garbage collection. I didn't think this all the way through.

Comment: @Otts— *users* is a global variable, so will not be garbage collected until the global execution context in which it exists expires (e.g. a new page is loaded). However, the object it references might be garbage collected sooner. *User.prototype.remove* only holds a reference to *users* for a very short time after the function is called and while it's executing, the identifier is resolved anew each time the function is called. It does not hold a reference beyond the execution of the function so should not create a "memory leak".

Comment: @RobG: It wasn't my intention to encourage a global variable for _users_. Instead I would use an IIFE respectively a scoped, local definition. I omitted this to avoid confusion.
My explanation for the non-existent memory leak referred to a non-global definition of users.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //More generic
    var a= {} , b = {};
    var users = [a,b];
    Object.prototype.removeFromArray = function(users) {
        var index = users.indexOf(this);
        users.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.dir(users); // a,b 
    a.removeFromArray(users);
    console.dir(users); //b
```